# While compiling the AOSP, is there a state where all .aidl files are transformed to corresponding .java file?

Tags: java, android-source, aidl

I want to do a static analysis on java part of AOSP, which requires all **.aidl** files to be transformed to **.java** files, so that the entire project tree is java only (ignoring cpp or other languages).

I have searched the doc and know that there is a executable tool named **aidl** which can help you transform a single .aidl file in a single time. However I am afraid that this is not the best way when considering the whole project.

So I am wondering if there is a state where all .aidl files are transformed to .java file while compiling the AOSP? If there really is, how to achieve that state?